# How do I turn the return value of a Perl sub into an arrayref?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I try the code like this:

```
my @rows = getRows($sth);
$self->stash(rows => \@rows);
```

The getRows is a sub function name, and the code works in template.
The $rows is a Array.

I write code like this:

```
$self->stash(rows => \getRows($sth));
```

The $rows is a REF, It's wrong.

If write code like this:

```
$self->stash(rows => getRows($sth));
```

The $rows is a HASH, It's wrong.

Is there any way to write the two line code in one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes.  You can write

```
$self->stash(rows => [getRows($sth)]);
```

The square brackets `[]` serve to create the desired reference.